# Invalid target value for key InstanceIds. Python boto3 ssm scripting error with InstanceIds?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

My python script to patch automatically has this one error in which the parameter InstanceIds is invalid. Where do I state the value for the InstanceIds in the script?

```
import boto3

ssm = boto3.client('ssm', region_name='us-east-1')
response = ssm.start_automation_execution(
    Parameters={
        'AutomationAssumeRole': [
                'parameters'
        ]
},
    DocumentName='document-name',
    Mode='Auto',
    TargetParameterName='test',
    Targets=[
        {
            'Key': 'InstanceIds',
            'Values': [ 'i-1234567890abcd' ]
 }
    ],

    MaxErrors='10'
)
```

This gives me the error message

```
Invalid target value for key InstanceIds
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The syntax looks correct from  what I can see in the documentation, is the instance id valid? Can you reproduce this scenario in the console?

Comment: @ChrisWilliams Yes, the error message is what I get from the console, and even then it wont work. Does it matter if the instance is on at the moment? I am running this command from another instance to test patch another.

Comment: I would suggest turning it on for registration of the automation target as it might be checking that the SSM agent is active

Comment: @ChrisWilliams The instance has been on for the testing though. Is there a permission I need to add?

Comment: I believe having the `AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore` policy attached to the instances role should be enough

Comment: @ChrisWilliams I believe this policy is already attached because running the remote patching script through aws cli works just fine, and the error seems to be coming from the key value

Comment: Sounds like you have the policy attached then

Answer (score 0):

***tl;dr:*** Make sure 'InstanceId' is listed as an input parameter in your automation document, and then try updating the Target.Key value you're using to `'ParameterValues'`.

This may depend somewhat on your implementation, but I was running into the same error as you, and my parameters matched yours, except that I was using `TargetParameterName='InstanceId'` instead of `TargetParameterName='test'`. I tried several different values for Target.Key and none of them worked, until I tried this and it worked:

```
Targets=[
            {
                'Key': "ParameterValues",
                'Values': [
                    "i-012345abcdeff",
                    "i-012345abcdefg"
                ]
            }
        ],
```

As an aside, I think they could probably stand to somewhat improve the error messages for this API for situations like this.